# carrierwave .store method throwing errors unknown regexp options @model=nil @mounted_as=nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a brand model

```
class Brand < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :activities, :attendees, :date, :description, :name, :place, :requirements_on_event, :requirements_other, :requirements_post_event, :requirements_pre_event, :target_students, :target_universities, :type, :image
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

I have the following in my brands table

```
t.string   "image"
```

and here is my image_uploader.rb

```
# encoding: utf-8

class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  # include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
   include CarrierWave::RMagick
  # include ::CarrierWave::Backgrounder::Delay

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  storage :file
  #storage :fog

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

   def extension_white_list
     %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
   end

end
```

I have these in my gemfile

```
#Picture Upload and Storage
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'carrierwave_backgrounder'
gem 'fog'
#gem 'aws-s3'
gem 'rmagick'
gem 'mini_magick
```

Now the problem is per the doc on carrierwave's github page

I try

`bundle exec rails c` and `rails c`

```
uploader = ImageUploader.new
```

I am getting this returned message in green

```
=> #<ImageUploader:0x007fcf2450bf68 @model=nil, @mounted_as=nil>
```

why is the `@model=nil` and `@mounted_as=nil`?

when I try to this

```
uploader.store!(/Users/judyngai/Desktop/brandspictures/circle_accupass.png)
```

I am getting this error

```
SyntaxError: (eval):2: unknown regexp options - jdyga
```

and if I try this

```
uploader.store!('/Users/judyngai/Desktop/brandspictures/circle_accupass.png')
```

carrierwave won't let me do it

```
CarrierWave::FormNotMultipart: You tried to assign a String or a Pathname to an uploader, for security reasons, this is not allowed.
```

I feel like I installed everything correctly. Its a rails 3.2.13 app. I commented out my carrierwave.rb because I am having trouble with fog and aws.

I just tried adding this to my model but still getting the same thing.

```
require 'carrierwave/orm/activerecord'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be calling `store!` method as below:

```
uploader.store!(File.open('/Users/judyngai/Desktop/brandspictures/circle_accupass.png'))
```

You should be passing an instance of `File` rather than a `String`. Hence, the error `You tried to assign a String or a Pathname to an uploader, for security reasons, this is not allowed.`